# Update column into Virtual Columns oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, alter-table, virtual-column

I would like to modify an existing column of my table in a virtual column. By opening the "SQL" tab in Oracle SQL Developer, the current column is (table DDL):

```
"ENABLED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT '1'
```

I would like to convert this column to a virtual column and get the following result:

```
"ENABLED" NUMBER(1,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("SCHEMA-NAME"."PRODUCT_ENABLED"("PRODUCT_ID")) VIRTUAL VISIBLE
```

To do this I wrote the following query:

```
  ALTER TABLE SCHEMA-NAME.SP_PRODUCT MODIFY ENABLED NUMBER(1,0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ("SCHEMA-NAME"."PRODUCT_ENABLED"("PRODUCT_ID")) VIRTUAL VISIBLE;
```

I'm not sure this is the right way to go, could you help me find the right solution?

Comment: Did this approach work?

Comment: I do not have the ability to immediately run the update query. I would like to know first if it was correct or not.

Comment: . . I haven't don't this particular action.  I would expect that you would need to drop the column first and then add it again as a generated column.

Comment: I do not know how to do this

Comment: `"SCHEMA-NAME"."PRODUCT_ENABLED"` should be a deterministic function.